# Load Items only after selecting a tab

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm working with Visual Studio and use C# for functionality and XAML for the GUI. As much as i've understood the command InitializeComponent() calls up the XAML and builds up the Elements from top to bottom as usual.
Using different tabs (TabControl) I wanted to ask if it's possible to load the elements only when the tab is selected, making the programm faster to start and unnecessary Elements (along with functions like a preselected Radiobutton) aren't needed to load.

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
<Grid>
     <TabControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <TabItem Header="First Tab" >
            <!-- This Tab will always load at first. -->                   
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Second Tab" > 
            <!-- Items in this Tab should only load when Tab is selected-->
        </TabItem>
     </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TabItem x:Name="SecondTab" Header="Second Tab" > 
        <Grid Visibility = "{Binding ElementName=SecondTab,Path=IsSelected,CONVERTERHERE"/>
    </TabItem>
```

You should bind Visibility of the content to IsSelected property.

Edit:
The issue in here is that IsSelected is boolean and Visibility property is of Visibility type. The common WPF approach is creating converter from boolean to visibility:

```
 class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is Boolean && (bool)value)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Declare it somewhere in your view in resource like this:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

Then use it:

```
<TabItem x:Name="SecondTab" Header="Second Tab" > 
        <Grid Visibility = "{Binding ElementName=SecondTab,Path=IsSelected,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </TabItem>
```

If you have any logic that needs to be invoked only if tab is selected then you should hook up to SelectionChanged event and invoke necessary logic if selected tab is your tab.

Comment: Tried to use it, but to be honest I don't understand what you mean with "CONVERTHERE" in this case. Also changing the visibility shouldn't change stuff like prechecking a radiobutton, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your help. After nesting the Visibility it finally allowed me to use them without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with XAML, but in WinForms one would catch the event of changing the tab and call the necessary code inside.

Comment: Found a way to get a "TabControl_SelectionChanged" but sadly when building up via InitializeComponent() it doesn't seem to actually change a Tab and thus I can't use it.

Comment: But how about building it when and only if user selects the very tab? E.g., I have an app with two tabs, on the first one I collect some info, and on the second I populate a list with this data. Info on the first tab can be updated, therefore I repopulate the list on the second tab every time user switches to that tab.

Comment: Probably that's the only option. Even though my Tabs have nothing in common and I just use em as a Selection of different "Tools". Gonna try to do it like that, thank you :)